# Printing a linked list. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, list, pointers

I am getting a segmentation fault in the following code:

```
void print_stack(Node * root) {
   while(root != NULL) {
     // print the node
     root = root->next;
   }
}
```

Whereas this works:

```
int print_stack(Node ** root) {

   Node * tmp = *root;

   while(*root != NULL) {
     // print the node
     *root = (*root)->next;
   }

   *root = tmp;
}
```

The question is what am I doing wrong? For both functions I am passing the address of a Node pointer to the head of the list. I am trying to get the first function to work because it seems more ideal (no pointer allocation and no permanent change to root pointer).. thanks.

**EDIT:** I have posted the code here: http://dpaste.com/477724/

Comment: Seg fault on the "root = root->next" line, or somewhere else in your program?

Comment: @Jollymorphic: I don't think so.. if next was NULL then the condition in the while loop should cause it to break. The second function works for certain.

Comment: If the exact posted code in the link is compiled, you should definitely get compilation errors rather than run time errors ( i.e., seg faults ).

Comment: @Mahesh: What compiler errors are you getting? I copied and pasted the code I just posted and was able to compile it without warning. This was using GCC 4.4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed the address of a Node pointer while the function takes just a Node pointer.

This:

```
print_stack(&main);
```

should be this:

```
print_stack(main);
```

Comment: It could be anything. 1) It's just the plain wrong type. 2) You try to access root->next which doesn't work on a pointer to a pointer and 3) You probably access something in the "// print the node" part which tries to access data members. This, like 2) will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Post all your code, showing the initialization of the linked list - seems like it should work.

```
class Node
{
public:
   Node();
   Node *next;
};

Node::Node()
{
   next = NULL;
}

void print_stack(Node * root) 
{    
   while(root != NULL) 
   {      // print the node     
      root = root->next;    
   } 
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   Node *root = new Node();
   Node *begin = root;
   for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
      Node *pNew = new Node();
      root->next = pNew;
      root = pNew;
   }
   print_stack(begin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yup, there's nothing wrong with the code you've shown. The problem must exist in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Hi Jeff.. thanks for taking the time to type up that solution. Unfortunately this doesn't really help me because you used a different implementation  through C++.. what I'm curious to know what I did wrong in my code and how I can fix that. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

There are compilation errors in the program you posted in the link.

**Error1:** `int print_stack(Node * root)` supposed to return an `int`. But it's definition isn't doing so.

**Error2:** In switch case, while calling `print_stack`, supposed to pass an argument of type `Node*` and not `Node**`. So, it should be `print_stack(main);`.

**Error3:** In `case u` of switch function, push functions arguments should be `push(&main, &d);`